# Breakpoint handling during execution vs debug mode Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, breakpoints

New to debugging question:

If I set Python 3.7 "breakpoint()" and it works fine during debug mode execution, but I forgot to rem it out for normal execution, what happens?

Are breakpoints simply ignored unless in debug mode?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: VSCode for the debugging, but I'm really interested in what happens on the runtime side which would just be a pure Python 3.7 install.  I'm suspecting that the Breakpoint is just ignored unless in debug mode, but wanted to verify.

Comment: So, this is a very noob question on debugging, but either no one else knows the answer or it's so obvious that no one wants to take the time.  Since I have a process that has been working completely fine in production, I'm going to assume that breakpoints do not need to be rem'ed out and that they are just ignored unless running in a debugger.

Comment: Seems I have found the answer on a different search.  breakpoint() is NOT ignored during runtime and will cause the debugger to be launched.  Turns out you can do a global variable to, essentially, ignore the breakpoints though so that they do not have to be remed in and out.  PYTHONBREAKPOINT=0 python3.7 debugger.py